# .htaccess for 2 CMS in different directories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla

My site is set up with 2 CMS syatems

In the root domain there is a Joomla website and in another directory called /word/ there is a wordpress directory.

The site originally was the wordpress site and this was moved to /word/ directory but to maintain all the original url's, I used mod_rewrite which works great until I insert the mod_rewrite for the Joomla site.

The mod_rewrite works great for the Joomla site but blocks all access to /word/ directory and 404 errors are thrown up. And if I leave the Joomla code out of the .htaccess I am left with the trailing /index.php/page name.

I have in my .htaccess file (This stops access to the /word/directory)

```
# Begin Joomla 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /word/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How can these 2 live together?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla comes with its own .htaccess template which should be in the root folder and called htaccess.txt.  Usually, I would rename to .htaccess and then un-comment this line:

```
# RewriteBase /
```

to:

```
RewriteBase /
```

My suggest would be to replace your "Joomla" section with the one provided by Joomla and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Nope that won't work, it was the first thing I tried, it works fine for items in the root but still throws up 404 errors when a click to the other directory

Comment: Actually, the more i think about it, the joomla .htaccess alone should work as long as directory permissions are set properly.  Think about the administrators login, this is a directory with is own index file like you're word directory.  Try removing everything but the included .htaccess file and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, but that still won't do what I want it to do as I'm mod-rewriting /word/ to the base /